# Liapunov functions

Tags: dynamical-systems

I would really like to see some very simple worked out or with some well pointed hints on these guys. i have two textbooks that outline the idea behind them, but both give only one example that are very contribbed imho. ( Non-Linear dynamics and intro to chaos By Steven H Strogatz) and (differential equations, dynamical systems and intro to chaos by Morris W. Hirsch.) Textbook or links to instructive material on this subject much appreciated.  ( im an ungrad and not from math so please don't bludgeon me to death thx.)

Comment: [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function) might be a good start.

Comment: Boyce and DiPrima is a popular undergrad diffeq textbook that has a section on this material, with a few examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Be careful that the name is spelled two different ways "Liapunov" or "Lyapunov", so when searching, try both!

These papers might be instructive:

- [*Lyapunov function methods*](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/L/StabLDC06/notes/SS_LYAPUNOV.pdf)
- [*MIT Lectures on Dynamic Systems and Control*](http://web.mit.edu/6.241/www/chapter_14.pdf)
- [*MIT - Finding Lyapunov Functions*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-243j-dynamics-of-nonlinear-systems-fall-2003/lecture-notes/lec7_6243_2003.pdf)
- [*A comparison of three methods of constructing Lyapunov functions*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021892895001204)
- [*Stability theory for systems of dierential equations with
  applications to power control in wireless networks*](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/esmd2/SmithKnightEssay.pdf)

**Books** These have a handful of pages each and I like the first two most.

- Modern Control Theory, W. Brogan (very nice write-up on the matter, with physical and electrical circuits)
- The Qualitative Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations, An Introduction, F. Brauer and J.A. Nohel
- Ordinary Differential Equations, V.I. Arnold
- Dynamics and Bifurcations, J. Hale and H Kocak
- Nonlinear systems, H.K. Khalil

There may be some applied materials from Physics areas that might also help.

Comment: Aren't you the helpful one! $\;1^+\;$

Comment: Ahhh, indeed, enjoy dinner, go home! Relax. Talk to you soon.